# Object has no attribute but also get global name not defined

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying my darnest to pull a variable from a text file to do some math in an trading bot algorithim.

This is my code. I have shortened it to get to the issue:

```
from botlog import BotLog
from botindicators import BotIndicators
from bottrade import BotTrade

class BotStrategy(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.output = BotLog()
    self.prices = []
    self.closes = [] # Needed for Momentum Indicator
    self.trades = []                #20 trades at 0.021 =  .042 
    self.currentPrice = ""      #after a day, add the BTC to 0.042 and adjust simultaneous trades
    self.currentClose = ""      #53 coins for 2500 simul trades per coin pair
    self.numSimulTrades = 100   #looks like dash ends at 2500 trades  eth ends at about     1000 trades total for all four would be about 208 coins
    self.indicators = BotIndicators()
    mid=0

    with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        mid=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        self.output.log(mid)
    mid=int(mid)

def tick(self,candlestick):
    self.currentPrice = float(candlestick.priceAverage)
    self.prices.append(self.currentPrice)

    #self.currentClose = float(candlestick['close'])
    #self.closes.append(self.currentClose)

    self.output.log("Price: "+str(candlestick.priceAverage)+"\tMoving Average: "+str(self.indicators.movingAverage(self.prices,5)))
    self.evaluatePositions()
    self.updateOpenTrades()
    self.showPositions()


def evaluatePositions(self):
    openTrades = []
    for trade in self.trades:
        if (trade.status == "OPEN"):
            openTrades.append(trade)

    if (len(openTrades) < self.numSimulTrades):
        if ((self.currentPrice) < self.indicators.movingAverage(self.prices,15)):
            self.trades.append(BotTrade(self.currentPrice,stopLoss=.0001))

    for trade in openTrades:
        if ((self.currentPrice + mid) > self.indicators.movingAverage(self.prices,15)) :
            trade.close(self.currentPrice)

def updateOpenTrades(self):
    for trade in self.trades:
        if (trade.status == "OPEN"):
            trade.tick(self.currentPrice)


def showPositions(self):
    for trade in self.trades:
        trade.showTrade()
```

With "self.mid" I get the error: 'Bot1' object has no attribute 'mid'
a if I remove the "self" I get: NameError: global name 'mid' is not defined

What am I doing wrong? I'm losing my mind!

Traceback was requested: This is the No Attribute:

```
user@user1:~/Desktop/bot/part3$ python backtest.py
90
Price: 0.0486309    Moving Average: None
Price: 0.04853957   Moving Average: 0.048585235
Trade opened
Entry Price: 0.04853957 Status: OPEN Exit Price: 
Price: 0.04847643   Moving Average: 0.0485489666667
Trade opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backtest.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "backtest.py", line 12, in main
    strategy.tick(candlestick)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 30, in tick
    self.evaluatePositions()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 46, in evaluatePositions
    self.currentPrice= float(self.currentPrice+self.mid)
AttributeError: 'BotStrategy' object has no attribute 'mid'
```

And this is "mid" not defined:

```
user@user1:~/Desktop/bot/part3$ python backtest.py
90
Price: 0.0486309    Moving Average: None
Price: 0.04853957   Moving Average: 0.048585235
Trade opened
Entry Price: 0.04853957 Status: OPEN Exit Price: 
Price: 0.04847643   Moving Average: 0.0485489666667
Trade opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backtest.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "backtest.py", line 12, in main
    strategy.tick(candlestick)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 30, in tick
    self.evaluatePositions()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 46, in    evaluatePositions
    if ((self.currentPrice + mid) >     self.indicators.movingAverage(self.prices,15)) :
    NameError: global name 'mid' is not defined
```

bottrade.py code:

```
from botlog import BotLog
import botstrategy 

def main(argv):
    currentMovingAverage = 0;
    tradePlaced = False
    typeOfTrade = False
    dataDate = ""
    orderNumber = ""
    dataPoints = []
    localMax = []
    currentResistance = 0.018
    mid = int(mid)


class BotTrade(object):
    def __init__(self,currentPrice,stopLoss=0):
        self.output = BotLog()
        prices = []
        self.status = "OPEN"
        self.entryPrice = currentPrice
        self.exitPrice = ""
     self.output.log("Trade opened")


        if (stopLoss):
            self.stopLoss = currentPrice - stopLoss

    def close(self,currentPrice):
    self.mid = int(mid)
     if currentPrice > (self.entryPrice + self.mid): #DASH likes about 0.000937, XRP about 0.000001, ETH likes  0.000855  XMR likes  0.000396
          #use ETH to start with, with less than 4 trades. you get about 1.7 BTC in a week - 4 trades @ 0.021=0.084 BTC. Daily is 0.24 
            self.status = "CLOSED"
            self.exitPrice = currentPrice
            self.output.log("Trade closed")

    def tick(self, currentPrice):
        if (self.stopLoss):
            if (currentPrice < self.stopLoss):
                self.close(currentPrice)


    def showTrade(self):
         tradeStatus = "Entry Price: "+str(self.entryPrice)+" Status: "+str(self.status)+" Exit Price: "+str(self.exitPrice)

        if (self.status == "CLOSED"):
            tradeStatus = tradeStatus + " Profit:! "
            if (self.exitPrice > self.entryPrice):
                tradeStatus = tradeStatus + " \033[92m"
            else:
                tradeStatus = tradeStatus + " \033[91m"

        tradeStatus = tradeStatus+str(abs((self.exitPrice) - (self.entryPrice)))+" \033[0m"

    self.output.log(tradeStatus)
```

Traceback from bottrade.py

```
user@user1:~/Desktop/bot/part3$ python backtest.py
Price: 1131.71486314    Moving Average: None
Price: 1103.73203402    Moving Average: 1117.72344858
Trade opened
Entry Price: 1103.73203402 Status: OPEN Exit Price: 
Price: 1108.36463027    Moving Average: 1114.60384248
Trade opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backtest.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
   File "backtest.py", line 12, in main
     strategy.tick(candlestick)
   File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 29, in tick
self.evaluatePositions()
      File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/botstrategy.py", line 46, in evaluatePositions
    trade.close(self.currentPrice)
    File "/home/user/Desktop/bot/part3/bottrade.py", line 30, in close
self.mid = int(mid)
NameError: global name 'mid' is not defined
```

Full display now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't used `self.mid` in this code. If you want us to help you, you need to show the real code and the full traceback.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run-time system is correct.  In the `mid` case, there is no variable `mid` defined in `evaluatePositions`.  Similarly, there is no object attribute `mid` for instances of `BotStrategy`.  Look at the difference in your initialization:

```
class BotStrategy(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.output = BotLog()
    self.prices = []
    self.closes = [] # Needed for Momentum Indicator
    ...
    mid=int(mid)
```

`mid` is a local variable of **init**, not an attribute.  Perhaps you need

```
    self.mid = int(mid)
```

and the use `self.mid` when you reference that value.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Not entirely. It does work for the botstrategy.py, but not for bottrade. I've added all the lines you have here into bottrade.py, but I'm still getting a "no attribute mid".   Mid is an integer, so maybe I don't need int(mid)?

Comment: We can't debug code until you supply the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the code above to include bottrade.py and it's traceback.

Comment: You did the same thing there: you tried to use a variable `mid` that doesn't exist.  This is in the same state as BotStrategy was before I suggested changes: no object attribute `mid`, and you trying to reference either that or a local variable.  You have to make the attribute and then reference it with `self.mid`.

Comment: I see my mistake and thank you for the assist.   To the person who downvoted this question - I am sorry I needed help. I searched for over an hour to find the solution to my problem, and for some reason you felt my question wasn't "worthy" of being asked. In this Thankgiving season, I hope you find peace and joy.